# How to re-initialise (state) array variable in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I'm making an API call.

And I'm getting response as :

```
var data =
[
    {a: 'a', b: 'b'}
]
```

And I want to set value of variable in state as `data`.

But it's not working . Giving error as =>

> ```
> Objects are not valid as a React child
> Ex: -
> state = {
> stateVariable: []
> }
> apiCall.then((data) => {
>   this.setState({ stateVariable: data  })
> })
> ```

Comment: `Objects are not valid as a React child`: this is related to how you're using `state.stateVariable` in your component rendering, not the `setState` call itself - you'll need to include your react component code if you want help debugging the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Objects are not valid as a React child
```

In react, you cannot render an object directly.

I feel you are trying to do something like this

```
<Text>{this.state.stateVariable}</Text>
```

It will not work because the value in there is an array.

To fix this, you can map it:

```
{this.state.stateVariable.map(data => <Text>{data.a} {data.b}</Text>)}
```

Secondly, You may already be mapping it or looping it but you're still getting the error. This is because if you render just `data` as in my map above, it is an object `{a:'a', b:'b'}` and this is not allowed in react.

So you have to make it `{data.a}` or `{data.b}`

Comment: Thank you for your response . But I have to reinitialize "stateVariable" for that I can pass it to a chart. As json data and
 "this.setState({ stateVariable: data  })"
this part is not working

Comment: According to the error you're having, it should not have anything to do with the `setState`. Is your apiCall and your setState in a `componentDidMount`?
Perhaps you can provide the code for the entire component so it'll be easier to know what is really going on.

Comment: Please can you provide more code snippet of your component so i can have a better understanding of the problem?

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    getNotificationData(EndPoints.NOTIFICATION, this.state.pageNumber, this.state.limit).then(notify => {
      this.setState({data: [...notify]});
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

Comment: Thank you for this. The componentDidMount seems fine. Please, can you show a snippet of the render function? That is probably where the problem is coming from.

Comment: <FlatList
     data={this.state.data}
 /> => This part was creating the problem in render function
Now setState is working properly.
Thanks Alot Man..... I was stuck on this issue from last 2 days.